# Error calling Informatica B2B Data Transformation with java API

Tags: informatica, b2b

I am trying to run DataTransformation from  java API and get the following error message:


`Failure while trying to create engine log /Informatica/9.1.0/DataTransformation/CMReports/Init/Events.cme- for more information see file://internal`

Could you please advise about the reason for this exception and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the user which is running the informatica Workflow through B2B doesn;t have the permission to create this log file. Please assign correct permission to this directory.

Please note that this is the log file created by Informatica DT or UDT Transformation and on failure you have to import this event.cme into Informatica DT for spotting the error.